# Lubuntu booting straight to Grub, sometimes saying cannot load kernel

Tags: kernel, grub, lubuntu

I recently installed Lubuntu via a USB drive. It works great, but I have found one major problem. Upon booting up my laptop, it opens two one of two things.

The first is a Grub command line. If I simply type *exit* as a command, the laptop proceeds to a normal boot.

Sometimes, however, it will open up to the grub line, with an error message, saying it cannot find the kernel / the kernel is not defined. (I wish I could take screenshots but that is not an option for this problem.

I have tried changing the boot options in BIOS.
I have tried a few suggested answers of setting the kernel proposed to similar questions.
None of this has worked.

I assume this is an issue where I need to establish what my kernel is and have the machine boot from that. I don't know how though.

Overall my laptop works, and so it is not the most pressing issue, but I would like to fix it.

If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this, I would be very grateful. Thanks! :)

**EDIT 1:**

Entered the command in the terminal `sudo update-grub`

Command succeeded.

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/lubuntu-grub-theme.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/lubuntu-grub-theme/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-21-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

Rebooted the computer several times to see if the same issue was present. Issue is still present, described below.

The error on grub appears like:

```
error: command failed
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

This can be circumvented by pressing 'c', entering the original grub menu, and entering the 'exit' command

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub`from a successful boot, reboot and test. Please [edit] the question and describe what you already tried and the result of my suggestion.

Comment: I ran the command. Rebooted the computer several times. Opened to grub twice and then to the previous error